# Select first option by default using v-model

Tags: vue.js

Can someone help with this problem? I have a dynamic select dropdown. The first default option of "Choose your location" is not visible by default. This is because of v-model. How can I get that working?
My parent component:

```
<template>
<div>

<Segments @select-segment-location-event="updateSegmentLocation" :segmentLocation="segmentLocation" />

</div>
</template>
```

My child component:

```
<template>
      <div class="container">
         <select v-model="segmentLocation" @change="selectSegmentLocation">
            <option selected disabled>Choose your location...</option>
            <option v-for="(segLoc, index) in segmentLocations" 
             :key="index"
            :value="segLoc">{{ segLoc.name }}</option>
         </select> 
      </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return {
      segmentLocations: [
            { value: "Residential", name: 'Residential building' },
            { value: "Workplace", name: 'Workplace' },
            { value: "Hospitality", name: 'Hospitality or Retail' },
            { value: "Real Estate", name: 'Real Estate' },
            { value: "Commercial Parking", name: 'Commercial Parking' },
            { value: "Fleets", name: 'Fleets' },
            { value: "Cities & Governments", name: 'Cities & Governments' },
            { value: "Corridor", name: 'Highway, Corridor or Petrol Station' }
    ],
    }
  }
   methods: {
    selectSegmentLocation() {
        this.$emit('select-segment-location-event', this.segmentLocation);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, You can add the `segementLocation` in the data option with a default value. Like `segmentLocation: 'Choose your Location...'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, the `segmentLocation` variable is passed as a prop to the `Segments` component.

You should avoid mutating a prop with v-model in the child component, because each component should only mutate it's own state.

I propose a few changes, add a new `selectedSegmentLocation` variable in your `data` method, with a default value of `"NOT_SELECTED"`  :

```js
data() {
  return {
    selectedSegmentLocation: "NOT_SELECTED",
    segmentLocations: []
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, update the `Choose your location...` option to have a value attribute:

```html
<option selected value="NOT_SELECTED" disabled>Choose your location...</option>
```

Now, update the v-model and the `selectSegmentLocation` method to use the new variable:

```html
<select v-model="selectedSegmentLocation" @change="selectSegmentLocation">
```

```js
selectSegmentLocation() {
  this.$emit('select-segment-location-event', this.selectedSegmentLocation);
}
```

If you still want to use the passed prop `segmentLocation` as a default value, use it in the `created()` hook, but you should have `'NOT_SELECTED'` as the default value if you want to show the `'Choose your location'` option.

```js
created() {
  this.selectedSegmentLocation = this.segmentLocation ? this.segmentLocation : "NOT_SELECTED";
}
```

And, if you want to be able to change the selected value from the parent, you can `watch` the `segmentLocation` property:

```js
watch: {
  segmentLocation() {
    if (this.segmentLocation) {
      this.selectedSegmentLocation = this.segmentLocation;
    }
  }
}
```